# How to change a property value of this.state in the child component's child

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Can't figure out how to set a specific property within this.state in parent component, from a child component of it's child component. I know how to pass a function to a child component and have it effect the parent that passed it, but it seems tricky to pass a function to a child of a child and have that set values in this.state of it's parent's parent. So this is three levels deep rather than two.

I don't necessarily need code or examples, although they will be welcomed. I just need the right angle to approach this from. Do I just pass a function from top level parent (through props) to the child, and the child never calls it and instead merely pipes it through via props to it's child where it is actually called in a click event? Not sure how this can connect back to parent of parent and change this.state values

Comment: Yes, passing functions down the chain of children is the expected way to manage this in vanilla react. If you find your state management needs are becoming complex enough that this no longer suffices, consider looking into a state management framework like Redux.

Comment: I think you answered my question, or at least verified how to approach this, which is what I asked about. I'll figure out how to code it. If you want to put your comment in an answer, I mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, passing functions down the chain of children is the expected way to manage this in vanilla react.

If you find your state management needs are becoming complex enough that this no longer suffices, consider looking into a state management framework like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). You can also use store such as Redux. Store data in the redux store, not the component, and use the actions in child to change data

```js
const Context = React.createContext();

class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            color: 'white'
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Context.Provider value={this.setState.bind(this)}>
                <React.Fragment>
                    <div style={{background: this.state.color}}>123</div>
                    <Child1/>
                </React.Fragment>
            </Context.Provider>
        );
    }
}

class Child1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <span>
                child1
                <Child2/>
            </span>
        );
    }
}

class Child2 extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Context.Consumer>
                {(setState) => (
                    <button onClick={() => { setState({color: 'red'}); }}>child2</button>
                )}
            </Context.Consumer>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I just simply do not know anything about redux yet. That's on the list. But I appreciate the advice and have up marked your answer, and ultimately, it's probably the best way to do it in complex situations.